# minimum of char array vars in sas

Tags: sas

I'm working to a code where I'm stuck at trying to find the minimum value  in a char string, please see sample code below:

```
data a;
array a(2) $ a1 a2;
array b(2) b1 b2;
a1='1,2,3,';a2= '1,3,4';
i=0;
do until (i>=2);
i=i+1;
b(i)=min(strip(tranwrd(a(i),","," ")));
end;

run;
```

I get the note below and null values for b(i).
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, '1 2 3' , at line 32 column 10.
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, '1 3 4' , at line 32 column 10.

Could you please suggest a way to get minimum of such string arrays.

Comment: How do you define the minimum of a string?  Why do your strings contain commas? What do the commas mean?

Comment: These strings were created in a step prior to this step in the code and they indicate some parameters, I need to be able to take the minimum of these parameters and use it later in the code.

Comment: What "parameters"? It looks like want to parse a string that has a delimited list of numbers and find the smallest number in that list.  But that is not stated clearly in the question.  Is there some reason that you cannot have the data in actual numeric variables instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a string expression to the MIN() function have it operate as if you had passed it numeric constants at compile time.  You could perhaps use the macro processor to help evaluate the strings as if they were numeric constants by using the `resolve()` function.

```
do i=1 to dim(a);
  b(i)=input(resolve(cats('%sysfunc(min(',a(i),'))')),32.);
end;
```

But it might be clearer and easier to just parse the strings and convert them to numbers in your code instead.

```
do i=1 to dim(a);
  do j=1 to countw(a(i),',');
    b(i)=min(b(i),input(scan(a(i),j,','),32.));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I converted them to numeric by adding an extra step to the code where I convert them to numeric and find the minimum then, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
data _null_;
  params = '1,2,3,';
  do i = 1 to count(params, ',') + 1;
    min_param = min(min_param,scan(params,i,','));
  end;
  put _all_;
run;
```

I'm sure you're capable of setting up arrays etc to do the same thing with multiple variables.